# Unity missing reference at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.16

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just bought template products in Unity expecting to learn some logic

i just encountered errors of CS0246 when importing. and it seems all coming from one package in Library
below is one of the error message.

**Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.16/Editor/Collab**/Presenters/CollabHistoryPresenter.cs(21,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BuildAccess' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

i am a beginner and i don't know how to handle on this kind of error.
can anyone kindly help me point out where and why this error happen?

Comment: Hi @twoFacesDalsoon, and welcome to Unity development. Unfortunately, a reference not being found could be A LOT of different things, from issues with your development environment, to the template itself. Could you point us to the template you are trying to use so maybe we could see what references its trying to use? Since it sounds like it is a paid template it might be hard to get a hold of it to test it out, but worth a shot. Also, any additional information you can provide - Unity version, Visual Studio version, etc. - would help as well

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with "template products". What are they?

Comment: its a game kit that help you create your own game without code writting

Comment: @dgates82 Its Horror FPS KIT from THUNDERWIRE STUDIO , contents are heavy and there are many libraries that i cant figure out what each of them doing. My Unity versions 2020.3.07f1 . anyway the cause seems to be package version mismatch

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. Keeping package versions in sync can be a trial. You'll want to get very familiar with the Unity Package Manager (UPM). Depending on what environment you're building for (Android, IoS, Windows, etc.) there are also External Dependency Managers that can save some headaches and wasted hours as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions for tracking down the issue. Hard to tell what is missing.

- close unity and delete Library and obj folders. Then open Unity again. It will re-sync those folders.
- disable collaborate from services window in 2019- or window/collaborate in 2020+ and see if the issue gets resolved.

Comment: I just updated thew newest version of Unity Collaborate from package manager and messages are gone . I would've tried ur suggestions if didnt work thank you!

Comment: Had that problem, deleted the cached packages and everything works again. Thanks. Under Linux, the cache folder is `~/.config/unity3d/cache/packages/packages.unity.com`

Answer (score 6):

I just updated from 2019.x to 2020.3.x and ran into this problem. I tried clearing my package cache and ensuring the Collaborate service was disabled (Window -> General -> Services), but neither worked.

What fixed it for me was removing the "Version Control" package (a "built in" package, I believe. Check your filter in package manager!). I was never using Collaborate or Plastic SCM, just git, so I don't know why this would cause a problem from a simple upgrade.

Comment: Worked for me on a new install of 2021.2 as I tried to upgrade from a 2019.4 project. "I was never using..." doesn't matter - I, too, use git separate from Unity - seems the version control package is installed with 2021. Just remove it and you're done.

Comment: Yes, I only stated that so others would know my setup and could compare it with theirs.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the Package Manager and removed Collaborate.  No idea how it got there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).